# Increasing Javascript Object value?

Tags: javascript, object

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code to increase the value of `loc` to 2 etc.

```js
var jeremy = {loc:1};

var move1 = function (car){
  car.loc++;
};

console.log(move1(jeremy));
```

Comment: your code is working well.

Comment: @ochi I think you are confusing things. Post/Pre increment shouldn't change anything in this case

Comment: @Epitouille fair comment. removed mine

Comment: Just do `return ++car.loc;` inside the `move1` function.

Comment: ES6 style also `const move1 = car => ++car.loc;`

Comment: what result do you expect from the function as return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`move1()` does not return a value and it doesn't need to to increment the value, depending on what you want.

Ignoring the use of `console.log()` do you want to simply increment the value or also does `move1()` **have** to return the value?

**Your existing code is working fine** as it incremented the value, without returning it. However, you printed the result of the function rather than the updated object. Just call `move1()` to update your object and then print the object to verify as seen below.

Again, there is no need to return the value if all you want is update the object.

```js
var jeremy = {loc:1};

var move1 = function (car){
  car.loc++;
};

move1(jeremy)
console.log(jeremy.loc);
```

If you really want to return the value as well, increment the value and return it, similar to below.

```js
var jeremy = {loc:1};

var move1 = function (car){
    return ++car.loc; // returns 2 and increments loc to 2.
};

console.log(move1(jeremy)); // returns 2 , value after increment
console.log(jeremy.loc); // returns 2 as increment has happened.
```

Note the previous example I changed `Car.loc++` to `++Car.loc`, though `Car.loc += 1` works too. The difference being that `return Car.loc++` returns the result **before** it was incremented, as seen below.

Yes, `var x = Car.loc++; return x;` also works but I felt it was important to highlight at this point that there is differences between `++x` and `x++`

See more info on that topic here [**Arithmetic operators - Increment++**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())

```js
var jeremy = {loc:1};

var move1 = function (car){
    return car.loc++; // returns 1 and not 2 but will increment loc to 2.
};

console.log(move1(jeremy)); // returns 1 , value before increment
console.log(jeremy.loc); // returns 2 as increment has happened.
```

Answer (score 2):

your move1 function doesn't return anything. You try to print (console.log) its return value.
You should try to print the value of "jeremy.loc" instead

Comment: this should be in comment as well.

Comment: that answer is wrong. every function javascript returns something and this is always - per definition - `undefined`. the op does not expect that value, because op is expecting something different, which is not stated in the question, possible would be the object or the value after incrementing.

Comment: technically yes. But it's obvious that the op expect its value incremented in its console.log. Since the op its a begginer, it's good sometimes to popularize a little bit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to return a value in your function.
In your code, jeremy.loc = 2 at the end, but the console.log function prints nothing since move1 doesn't return anything.
Here is the code with the return syntax :

```js
var jeremy = {loc:1};

var move1 = function (car){
  car.loc++;
  return(car.loc);
};
console.log(move1(jeremy));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs a return value, and you can use ++car.loc instead of car.loc++. ++car.loc will increment the variable before the return statement. Writing car.loc++ will increment the variable after the return. Happy coding!

```
 var jeremy = {loc:1};

 var move1 = function (car){
     return ++car.loc;
 };

 console.log(move1(jeremy));
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
var jeremy = {loc:1};

var move1 = function (car){
  car.loc++;
  return car;
};

console.log(move1(jeremy));
```

Comment: Why answering your own after others gave you exactly the same solution which you clearly saw before answering considering the timestamps and your comments?